# Determine if directory is the root directory

Tags: perl

I am trying to traverse the directory tree upwards, searching for a given directory name, if the directory is found, I should `chdir` to it, otherwise give an error message. For example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Cwd qw(getcwd);

die "Base directory not found!" if (!gotoDir()); 

sub gotoDir {

   my $baseDir = '.test';
   my $curdir = getcwd();

   while (1) {
      return 1 if (-d $baseDir);
      if (! chdir("..")) {
         chdir($curdir);
         return 0;
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is that `chdir` does not fail when going beyond the root, so the above program enters an infinite loop if `.test` is not found.

Of course, I could just test for `/` since I am on Linux, but I would like to do this in a system independent manner.

Comment: For me it is hanging on `use Cwd;`

Comment: A .. directory exists in sub directories but not the root.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html : "...we recommend you use the `File::Spec` modules wherever portability is a concern." As @Gnouc suggests, test on what `File::Spec->rootdir()` returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Gnouc has answered, the [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Spec) module has a portable representation of the root directory with its `rootdir` method.

This is how I would write your `goto_dir` subroutine. Note that capital letters are conventionally reserved for global identifiers like `Package::Names`.

I think it is best to pass the directory you are searching for as a parameter to the subroutine to make it more general. I have also written it so that the subroutine does a `chdir` to the `.test` directory if it is is found, which is what you say you want but not what your own solution tries to do.

Finally, since portability is important, I have used `File::Spec->updir` in place of a literal `'..'` to refer to the parent of the current directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Cwd 'cwd';
use File::Spec;

goto_dir('.test') or die 'Base directory not found!';


sub goto_dir {
   my ($base_dir) = @_;

   my $original_dir  = cwd;

   while () {

      if (-d $base_dir) {
        chdir $base_dir;
        return 1;
      }
      elsif (cwd eq File::Spec->rootdir) {
        chdir $original_dir;
        return 0;
      }
      else {
        chdir File::Spec->updir;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) to get the root directory:

```
$ perl -MFile::Spec -E 'say File::Spec->rootdir()'
/
```

Answer (score 1):

`File::Spec` is great for obtaining what the root directory *is*, but for testing whether a given directory is or isn't that is not so easy. For that you likely want to use `stat` and compare if the `dev` and `ino` fields are equal:

```
use File::stat;

my $rootstat = stat(File::Spec->rootdir);

...

my $thisstat = stat($dir);
if( $thisstat->dev == $rootstat->dev and $thisstat->ino == $rootstat->ino ) {
   say "This is the root directory";
}
```

This avoids problems of the string-formatted form of a path to the directory, as it may be that you have the path `../../../../../..` for example.