# How to figure out if the current directory is the root in C?

Tags: c, directory

I am currently doing an assignment where I need to implement the functionality of `pwd` without using `getcwd` or `getenv`. However, am stuck in an infinite loop because when I use `chdir("..")` it seems to route me back to the same directory once I reach the root. I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981733/determine-if-directory-is-the-root-directory), but it was solved using a perl module so that didn't help.

My first thought was to keep track of the previous directory name and compare it with the current directory name to see if they matched, but I can't see any way to do that because I don't have the size of the directory name and there are null characters between the name of each file or directory in `d_name`.

Here is my code so far (note that it probably has other bugs as well, but I need to solve this first):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void get_path(char *path, int path_len);

int main(void)
{
   int path_len = -1;
   char path[PATH_MAX];

   /* get and print the path */
   get_path(path, path_len);
   path[0] = '\0';
   printf("%s\n", path);

   return 0;
}

/* get the path from the current directory to the root */
void get_path(char *path, int path_len)
{
   struct dirent *dirp;
   DIR *dp;

   /* open current dir */
   if ((dp = opendir(".")) == NULL)
   {
      perror("mypwd");
      exit(1);
   }

   /* go through this dir */
   while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
   {
      /* found its parent */
      if (strcmp(dirp->d_name, "..") == 0)
      {
         /* on to a new path */
         path_len++;
         if (path_len > PATH_MAX)
         {
            fprintf(stderr, "path too long\n");
            exit(1);
         }

         /* go to parent and continue */
         chdir("..");
         get_path(path, path_len);

         /* add this name to our path */
         strcat(path, dirp->d_name);
      }
   }

   closedir(dp);
}
```

How can I figure out of I have reached the file root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inode number of the parent directory of the root directory is 2, the same as the inode number of the root directory itself (and the device numbers are the same).  At least, this is true in classic Unix file systems — and some modern ones (probably all of them).

On my Mac, I can run:

```
$ ls -lid /. /..
2 drwxr-xr-x  34 root  wheel  1088 Apr 25 07:55 /.
2 drwxr-xr-x  34 root  wheel  1088 Apr 25 07:55 /..
$
```

Note that the root directory of a (mounted) file system has inode number 2 too on disk, but when you `stat()` the root directory of a mounted file system, you get a different inode and device number for the parent directory.

For example, on a Mac again, `/private/var/vm/` is mounted:

```
$ ls -lid /private/var /private/var/vm /private/var/vm/. /private/var/vm/..
13212009 drwxr-xr-x  26 root  wheel  832 Sep 26  2017 /private/var
       2 drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel  192 May  5 12:44 /private/var/vm
       2 drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel  192 May  5 12:44 /private/var/vm/.
13212009 drwxr-xr-x  26 root  wheel  832 Sep 26  2017 /private/var/vm/..
$
```

And using a custom `fstat` program, you can see the device numbers changing:

```
$ fstat /private/var /private/var/vm /private/var/vm/. /private/var/vm/.. / /. /..
   Mode      Inode Links   UID   GID     Size    Modtime        Dev       RDev File
0040755   13212009    26     0     0      832 1506482024   16777223          0 /private/var
0040755          2     6     0     0      192 1525549483   16777221          0 /private/var/vm
0040755          2     6     0     0      192 1525549483   16777221          0 /private/var/vm/.
0040755   13212009    26     0     0      832 1506482024   16777223          0 /private/var/vm/..
0040755          2    34     0     0     1088 1524668138   16777223          0 /
0040755          2    34     0     0     1088 1524668138   16777223          0 /.
0040755          2    34     0     0     1088 1524668138   16777223          0 /..
$
```

GNU `stat` and BSD `stat` commands produce the same device number information, but their output is more verbose and/or more unreadable.